# Finding the number of trials required for a value to be within a certain range in a discrete distribution at a certain probability

Tags: probability, distributions

In a survey of random questions, Jane can reply with either of the two possible answers; 'Yes' or 'No'.
The theoretical probability of Jane selecting 'Yes' for any random question in the survey is (p).

0 < (p) < 1 and (p) is a decimal with two decimal places (i.e. (p) can be 0.00, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, ..., 0.98, 0.99, 1.00)

However, since neither you nor Jane know the value of (p), you decide to conduct an experiment.

Whenever Jane answers a question, you are presented with:

- a running total of the number of questions Jane has answered (Q)

and

- a running total of the number of times Jane has said 'Yes' (Y)

Therefore the experimental probability (e) of Jane saying 'Yes' is (Y)/(Q), and as the number of trials approaches infinity, the experimental probability (e) should approach the value of (p). However you can only conduct a finite number of trials to approximate the value of (p).

So for example:

The first question Jane says Yes. (e = 1/1 = 1)

The second question Jane says Yes. (e = 2/2 = 1)

The third question Jane says No. (e = 2/3 = 0.667)

The fourth question Jane says Yes. (e = 3/4 = 0.75)

The fifth question Jane says Yes. (e = 4/5 = 0.8)

The sixth question Jane says No. (e = 4/6 = 0.667), etc.

So when Jane has answered (Q) questions, the total amount of experimental probabilities will be (Q)+1. For example when (Q) = 4, the possible experimental probabilities (e) at that point are 0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75 and 1.

However, obviously it would be expected that experimental probabilities with values closer to (p) would have a higher probability of being observed in the probability distribution for a given value of (Q) of all the possible experimental probabilities. So in the above example, if (p) = 0.27, then the experimental probability of 0.25 would have a higher probability of being observed in the probability distribution out of all possible probabilities (0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75 and 1).

Assuming the experimental probabilities are distributed evenly around the theoretical probability (p) (meaning it may be similar to a normal distribution but can be skewed in one direction and all points on the distribution are discrete), what is the value of (Q) at which the experimental probability (e) is within 0.02 of the theoretical probability (p) at least 90% of the time?

For example, if (p) = 0.13, what value of (Q) will result in there being a 90% chance or greater that in a distribution of all possible values of (e) for that value of (Q) around the theoretical probability (p),

0.11 <= (e) <= 0.15?

If this question is a bit unclear, please let me know as I'm new to this and not an expert on probability.